# How to document a makefile?

Tags: makefile, documentation-generation

Is there a way to write "standard" comments in a Makefile to later feed them to a Doxygen-like program so as to output a nice (HTML or man for instance) documentation ? I'd like to have a clear overview of my main targets somewhere but nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One nice touch is to provide a phony `help` target that prints a summary of targets and options. From the Linux kernel `Makefile`:

```
help:
        @echo  'Cleaning targets:'
        @echo  '  clean           - Remove most generated files but keep the config and'
        @echo  '                    enough build support to build external modules'
        @echo  '  mrproper        - Remove all generated files + config + various backup files'
        @echo  '  distclean       - mrproper + remove editor backup and patch files'
        @echo  ''
        @echo  'Configuration targets:'
        @$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/scripts/kconfig/Makefile help
        @echo  ''
```

It might be a bit of work to maintain the documentation this way, but I find it nicely separates what is intended for "users" versus what is intended for people maintaining the `Makefile` itself (inline comments).

Comment: Maybe I am not patient enough but I doubt there's anything else besides what you mentionned. Many thanks !!

Comment: If you want some sort of automated stuff take a look at [make-help](https://github.com/gibatronic/make-help).

Answer (score 61):

The following is a simpler solution that does not require defining user functions or aggregating help text away from the rules they document.

```
# This is a regular comment, that will not be displayed

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
## This is a help comment. The purpose of this Makefile is to demonstrate
## a simple help mechanism that uses comments defined alongside the rules
## they describe without the need of additional help files or echoing of
## descriptions. Help comments are displayed in the order defined within
## the Makefile.
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------

help:     ## Show this help.
    @sed -ne '/@sed/!s/## //p' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

build:    ## Build something.

install:  ## Install something.

deploy:   ## Deploy something.

format:   ## Help comments are display with their leading whitespace. For
          ## example, all comments in this snippet are aligned with spaces.
```

Running `make` or `make help` results in the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
This is a help comment. The purpose of this Makefile is to demonstrate
a simple help mechanism that uses comments defined alongside the rules
they describe without the need of additional help files or echoing of
descriptions. Help comments are displayed in the order defined within
the Makefile.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
help:     Show this help.
build:    Build something.
install:  Install something.
deploy:   Deploy something.
format:   Help comments are display with their leading whitespace. For
          example, all comments in this snippet are aligned with spaces.
```

Comment: This is brilliant. But take care copying it, those indented lines **MUST USE TABS**. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop

Comment: To make the help text align properly add `| column -tl 2`  to the `@sed` command

Comment: @balki can u please show full command with `| column -tl ` ?

Comment: @DemetryPascal ` @sed -ne '/@sed/!s/## //p' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | column -tl 2`
See: https://gitea.balki.me/balki/makepac/src/branch/main/Makefile#L10

Answer (score 12):

In a makefile such as :

```
install: ## Do a
  @echo "foo"

start: ## Do b
  @echo "bar"

test: ## Do c
  @echo "baz"
```

```
help:
  @egrep -h '\s##\s' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m  %-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

Will output :

[image]

Comment: Amazing @Rose 
This works like charm on macOS 

Comment: This looks really nice, thanks! I tried to replace the hardcoded colors with `tput setaf 3`, but didn't manage to.

Comment: This has a shortcoming when the Makefile includes other makefiles, because the grep result changes to be `Makefile:target: ## docs`. It can be fixed by changing the awk separator to `FS = ":[^:]*?## "`

Comment: This worked to "pretty" the output for me on MacOS (senoma) where the answer from "frelling" along with the addition from "balki"  did not, I believe due to an incompatible version of column in MacOS.

Answer (score 8):

I made my own solution using a short Perl script that formats the help as other GNU tools:

```
SCRIPT_VERSION=v1.0
SCRIPT_AUTHOR=John Doe

all:                ##@Build Build all the project 

clean:              ##@Cleaning Remove all intermediate objects

mrproper: clean     ##@Cleaning Remove all output and interemediate objects

HELP_FUN = \
    %help; while(<>){push@{$$help{$$2//'options'}},[$$1,$$3] \
    if/^([\w-_]+)\s*:.*\#\#(?:@(\w+))?\s(.*)$$/}; \
    print"$$_:\n", map"  $$_->[0]".(" "x(20-length($$_->[0])))."$$_->[1]\n",\
    @{$$help{$$_}},"\n" for keys %help; \

help: ##@Miscellaneous Show this help
    @echo -e "Usage: make [target] ...\n"
    @perl -e '$(HELP_FUN)' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @echo -e "Written by $(SCRIPT_AUTHOR), version $(SCRIPT_VERSION)"
    @echo -e "Please report any bug or error to the author."
```

Which gives this:

```
$ make help
Usage: make [target] ...

Miscellaneous:
  help                Show this help

Build:
  all                 Build all the project

Cleaning:
  clean               Remove all intermediate objects
  mrproper            Remove all output and interemediate objects

Written by John Doe, version v1.0
Please report any bug or error to the author.
```

Comment: A little improvement to the HELP_FUN bit: replace `if/^(\w+)\s*:` with `if/^([\w-_]+)\s*:` in order to allow targets of the type "this-target" or "that_target" as well.

Comment: This is fantastic! How could it be extended to allow for multi-line descriptions?

Comment: @nowox Can u please change the function to return results as sorted?

Answer (score 1):

[Self-Documenting Makefiles](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/print/article/self-documenting-makefiles) (John Graham-Cumming, 2005) lets you write the help alongside each rule. This is a lightweight and highly nifty solution that works at least with GNU Make.

Here's my [slightly modified version](https://github.com/simonmichael/hledger/commit/1b912387fab8384619cc037731df0ba971c16de7) (def-help-section helps organize long lists of rules).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version that also strips away the dependencies of a target and aligns the help strings to an even column.

```
help:   ## Show this help.
    @sed -ne 's/^\([^[:space:]]*\):.*##/\1:\t/p' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | column -t -s $$'\t'

image: src/*.s src/*.c src/**/*.c   ## Build the image
    riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc $^ -march=rv32i_zicsr -Wall -ggdb -O0 -o image -ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc

launch: ## Image Launch the image in renode
    renode --net vexriscv.resc --console
```

Output

```
help:    Show this help.
image    Build the image
launch:  Image Launch the image in renode
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [MakeHelp](https://github.com/mrdor44/MakeHelp) library exactly for that purpose. It lets you write the rule docs above each rule. Very easy to use.

I find it different from the other self-documenting Makefiles here as it has no repetitiveness and allows multiline docs and private rules.

Answer (score 0):

One more example:
Allow to write help message BEFORE command line.

You can use ":" in the help message to print it in a separate column.

```
## Another help message with data: in a separate column
test::
    echo ""

## Print this help
help::
    @awk '/^## /{c=substr($$0,3);next}c&&/^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_/-]+:/{print substr($$1,1,index($$1,":")),c}1{c=0}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | column -s: -t -W 2,3 -o " "
```

Output:

```
test       Another help message with data                           in a separate column
help       Print this help
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow writing a help message BEFORE the command line and divide it into sections

writing a help message BEFORE the command line based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566974/23306035
divide it into sections based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796664/23306035

```
build_test_1:
    echo ""

###@clean Help: message for clean_test_1
clean_test_1:
    echo ""

###@build Help: message for build_test_2
build_test_2:
    echo ""

###@clean Help: message for clean_test_2
clean_test_2:
    echo ""

### help: Print this help
help: #check build clean upload
    @awk ' \
        match($$0,/^###(@(\w+))? [Hh]elp: /,m) \
        {c=m[2];h=substr($$0,RLENGTH);next} \
        h&&/^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_/-]+:/ \
        {help[c][idx[c]++]=sprintf("\033[36m%s\033[0m\t%s", substr($$1,1,index($$1,":")-1),h)} \
        1{c=0;h=0} \
        END{ \
            n=asorti(help, help_); \
            for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) { \
                if(help_[c]){indent="  ";printf "\n%s:\n", help_[c]}\
                asort(help[help_[c]]); \
                for(x in help[help_[c]]){print indent help[help_[c]][x]} \
            } \
        }' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | column -s$$'\t' -tL
```

Output:

````
build:
  build_test_1   message for build_test_1
  build_test_2   message for build_test_2

clean:
  clean_test_1   message for clean_test_1
  clean_test_2   message for clean_test_2```
````