# Can I generate a Makefile help without listing down all targets?

Tags: makefile, gnu

My Makefile looks like this:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help

.PHONY: build clean-build start stop ssh getip

app = cp

help:
        @echo "Please use \`make <target>' where <target> is one of"
        @echo "build  To start building docker container"
        @echo "clean-build   Build from scratch without cache"
        @echo "start  Start up container build from build or clean-build"
        @echo "stop  Stop and delete container"
        @echo "ssh  Access container via ssh"
        @echo "getip   Get ip of container via docker inspect"

build:
        docker build -t cdn/$(app) .

clean-build:

        docker build --no-cache -t $(app) .
```

My question is, without adding all of my targets manually, is there a way for me to generate a help section that lists down all the targets in my file ?

Comment: How can Make possibly know what "getip" means? Or do you just want a list of targets *without* descriptions?

Comment: See related questions: [How do you get the list of targets in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219255/how-do-you-get-the-list-of-targets-in-a-makefile) - [How to automatically generate a Makefile help command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730218/how-to-automatically-generate-a-makefile-help-command) [How to document a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889035/how-to-document-a-makefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way for me to generate a help section that lists down all the targets in my file ?

**No.**

As others have mentioned, `make` has no default way of printing out *what* your targets do.

As for listing all targets from the command line, in `bash` you can issue the following command to get a list of all possible targets:

```
make  <TAB> <TAB>
```

Comment: That's not Make listing possible targets, that's the shell listing local files.

Comment: @Beta. No, that command actually does list targets for a makefile. Try it out for yourself...

Comment: I did. What version of Make are you using, and in what shell?

Comment: GNU make: 3.82   /  bash 4.2.45

Comment: In order for the tab to work you have to have the right shell completion customization packages installed.  Only filename completion is built into the shell directly, but most GNU/Linux distributions these days do provide an extensive set of additional completion customizations, which recognize commands (like `make`) and customize the shell's TAB completion to do special things for that command.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used this. It is not intuitive, but it does output a list of available targets. Granted this does not provide an explanation of what each target does, but I've found that this is so much better than nothing.

```
help:
    @echo "Available targets:"
    @$(MAKE) -pRrq -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) : 2>/dev/null | awk -v RS= -F: '/^# File/,/^# Finished Make data base/ {if ($$1 !~ "^[#.]") {print $$1}}' | sort | egrep -v -e '^[^[:alnum:]]' -e '^$@$$' | xargs
```