# How to automatically generate a Makefile help command

Tags: macos, unix, makefile, gnu

I recently found [this article online](http://marmelab.com/blog/2016/02/29/auto-documented-makefile.html), that explains how to setup a `make help` target that will automatically parse the Makefile for comments and display a nicely formatted help command.

It parses:

```
install: ## Install npm dependencies for the api, admin, and frontend apps
    @echo "Installing Node dependencies"
    @npm install

install-dev: install ## Install dependencies and prepared development configuration
    @./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install
    @cp -n ./config/development.js-dist ./config/development.js | true

run-frontend-dev: webpack.PID ## Run the frontend and admin apps in dev (using webpack-dev-server)
```

Into:

```
install              Install npm dependencies for the api, admin, and frontend apps
install-dev          Install dependencies and prepared development configuration
run-frontend-dev     Run the frontend and admin apps in dev (using webpack-dev-server)
```

But for some reason I can't get it working (on OSX at least). With this target:

```
help: ## Show the help prompt.
  @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

When I run:

```
make help
```

I just get:

```
$ make help
make: Nothing to be done for `help'.
```

I've tried all of the different solutions from the comments in the article too, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Also, what would a variation on the script be that would allow comments to be placed on a line *before* the target, instead of after it. Like so:

```
# Build the source files with Babel.
build: $(shell find lib)
    @rm -rf build
    @mkdir -p build
    @$(babel) lib $(babel_options)

# Seed the database with fake data.
db-fake:
    @$(run) node bin/run-sql fake
```

Here is the full Makefile in question:

```
# Options.
DEBUG ?=
SOURCEMAPS ?= true
WATCH ?=

# Variables.
bin = ./node_modules/.bin
tests = $(shell find test/routes -depth 1)
shorthand-tests = $(patsubst test/routes/%.js,test-%,$(tests))

# Binaries.
babel = $(bin)/babel
mocha = $(bin)/mocha
node = node
nodemon = $(bin)/nodemon
run = heroku local:run

# Babel options.
babel_options = \
    --out-dir build \
    --copy-files

# Sourcemaps?
ifneq ($(SOURCEMAPS),false)
babel_options += --source-maps
endif

# Watch?
ifdef WATCH
babel_options += --watch
endif

# Development?
ifneq ($(NODE_ENV),production)
node = $(nodemon)
endif

# Debug?
ifdef DEBUG
node += debug
mocha += debug
endif

# Default.
default: help ## Default.

# Build the source files with Babel.
build: $(shell find lib) ## Build the source files with Babel.
    @rm -rf build
    @mkdir -p build
    @$(babel) lib $(babel_options)

# Seed the database with fake data.
db-fake: ## Seed the database with fake data.
    @$(run) node bin/run-sql fake

# Reset the database, dropping everything and the creating again.
db-reset: ## Reset the database, dropping everything and the creating again.
    @$(run) node bin/run-sql drop
    @$(run) node bin/run-sql create

# Seed the database with test data.
db-seed: ## Seed the database with test data.
    @$(run) node bin/run-sql seed

# Show the help prompt.
help: ## Show the help prompt.
  @awk '/^#/{c=substr($0,3);next}c&&/^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]+:/{print substr($1,1,index($1,":")),c}1{c=0}' mm.mk | column -s: -t

# Open the PSQL interface.
psql: ## Open the PSQL interface.
    @psql contentshq

# Run the development server.
server: ## Run the development server.
    @$(run) $(node) bin/api

# Start the local postgres server.
start: ## Start the local postgres server.
    @pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

# Stop the local postgres server.
stop: ## Stop the local postgres server.
    @pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast

# Run all of the tests.
test: ## Run all of the tests.
    @$(run) $(mocha) $(tests)

# Run specific route tests.
$(shorthand-tests): ## Run specific route tests.
    @$(run) $(mocha) test/routes/$(subst test-,,$@).js

# Watch the source files with Babel.
watch: ## Watch the source files with Babel.
    @WATCH=true $(MAKE) build

# Phony targets.
.PHONY: help
.PHONY: test
.PHONY: watch
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, if I hit backspace three times start at the beginning of the `@awk` line, which removes the `<space><space><newline>` characters, and retype them.. it seems to work. Is there something to do with Makefiles acting weird with certain newline characters?

Comment: You don't by chance have a `\` at the end of the line starting `help: `, do you? Also, the next line is supposed to start with a tab, but in your cut and paste it looks like two spaces. That should trigger an error.

Comment: Ah shoot that's totally it, for some reason I thought Makefiles needed spaces, but they needed tabs. Instead of erroring it's just giving me the "nothing to be done" output though.

Comment: What `make` are you using? All the makes I know will give you a syntax error for a line starting with a space, unless it thinks that the line is a continuation.

Comment: Yeah, and I've definitely received those syntax errors before. I'm not sure what's up. Using `GNU Make 3.81`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a little awk script which will handle the case where the comment comes before the target name. I used `column` to put the text into columns, but you could do it in awk using a printf (and, if you wanted, adding the console codes to colorize the output); the advantage of using `column` is that it works out the column width automatically.

You'd insert it into the Makefile in the same way:

```
.PHONY: help

# Show this help.
help:
    @awk '/^#/{c=substr($$0,3);next}c&&/^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]+:/{print substr($$1,1,index($$1,":")),c}1{c=0}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | column -s: -t
```

Comment: When I try running that I get: `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> /^#/{c=substr(, <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1`

Answer (score 5):

You need a `help` rule that will actually extract and print the messages. Assuming the article you're talking about is http://marmelab.com/blog/2016/02/29/auto-documented-makefile.html, this is what you're looking for.

```
.PHONY: help

help:
    @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

Your docs before the command approach might be doable but will require some more work. Most UNIX commands work line by line so it's easier to do with the comments as specified in the article.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to show the `make help` target I had defined, but I actually do have that in the `Makefile`, but it still outputs `make: Nothing to be done for 'help'.` If it wasn't there it would say `make: *** No rule to make target 'help'.  Stop.`

Comment: The `.PHONY` specification is a GNU extension that tells `make` that `help` is a "fake" target without any dependencies etc. Without that, it decides that there's nothing to be done and will print your message.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I would like to add that replacing `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` with `$(word 1,$(MAKEFILE_LIST))` is probably better as `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` may contain multiple values if some other file was included

Comment: @dhvcc Thanks. I forgot about this answer and it's been a while since I used `make` so I'll take your word for it. :)

Comment: +1 for @ccvhd's recommendation of using `$(word 1,$(MAKEFILE_LIST))`. I was baffled why all of my targets starting showing as "Makefile" and didn't realize it started after I `include`d another file. This suggestion brought back the actual target names.

Answer (score 0):

I like [risi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35730928/956967)'s answer and made a little enhancements to it. With this change, any comment in the Makefile starts with ## will be passed though into help text, while ## comment right before a make target will render as a help for that target.

```
# this line does not go into help
##
## This is the help header 1
## This is the help header 2
##
# The above line is ##<SPACE><SPACE> which inserts a line break

.PHONEY: help

## Print this help
help:
    @awk '/^## / \
        { if (c) {print c}; c=substr($$0, 4); next } \
         c && /(^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_-]+:)/ \
        {print $$1, "\t", c; c=0} \
         END { print c }' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

# This target will not appear in help
target0:
    @echo action 0

## Description 1
target1:
    @echo action 1

## Description 2
target2: target1
    @echo action 2

##
## This can be a description of another subsection
##

## Description 3
target3:
    @echo action 3

##
## Some text to finish up the help.
##
```

Running "make help" on this Makefile will generate:

```
This is the help header 1
This is the help header 2

help:    Print this help
target1:         Description 1
target2:         Description 2

This can be a description of another subsection

target3:         Description 3

Some text to finish up the help.
```

Couldn't use "column" like Risi's solution because it interfers with help output not associated with target.